# why oracle apps home page not showing submenus for responsibility in oracle apps after migration

Tags: oracle, oracle-ebs, oracle-apps

why oracle apps home page not showing submenus for responsibility in oracle apps after migration

need to get the submenus under the responsibility in oracle apps home page which is missing.

Solution:
System Administrator Responsibility
Requests > Run the following:
"Synchronize WF LOCAL tables"&"Workflow Directory Services User/Role Validation concurrent   program"

After this has completed, return to the home page
Find the "Personalize" button
Customize Applications Navigator

> GO >All Responsibilities > Select All > Show All> Apply

After the steps are completed, then all the responsibilities will be displayed on the home page.
tried above solution but failed.

Comment: Possibly a caching issue?   Does it happen after bouncing DB and mid-tier?